# Why MySQL Cluster insert too slow

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Cluster work on 4 machines (version is 7.3.10): 
- 2 machines for 2 MGM node(and SQL node) 
- 2 machines for 2 data node

but it too slow when insert ( **i use batch insert of 3000 statements per transaction, it just about 900 per second** ), then trying to use mysqldump is the same slow, and i have been lookup MySQL official configuration, but have no idea to resolve, here is some info :

CPU: 32 processors  MEMORY: 64GB  NETWORK: 10000Mb/s

-------- config.ini ---------

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
BackupMaxWriteSize=1M
BackupDataBufferSize=16M
BackupLogBufferSize=4M
BackupMemory=20M
BackupReportFrequency=10
MemReportFrequency=30
LogLevelStartup=15
LogLevelShutdown=15
LogLevelCheckpoint=8
LogLevelNodeRestart=15
DataMemory=12288M
IndexMemory=2048M
MaxNoOfTables=4096
MaxNoOfTriggers=3500
NoOfReplicas=2
StringMemory=25
DiskPageBufferMemory=512M
SharedGlobalMemory=256M
LongMessageBuffer=32M
BatchSizePerLocalScan=512
FragmentLogFileSize=64M
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=30
RedoBuffer=64M
MaxNoOfExecutionThreads=8
StopOnError=false
LockPagesInMainMemory=1
TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=32000
TimeBetweenWatchdogCheckInitial=60000
TransactionInactiveTimeout=60000
HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=15000
HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=15000
MaxNoOfAttributes=10000
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=1024
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=512
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=20000
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
TimeBetweenGlobalCheckpoints=1000
TimeBetweenEpochs=200
```

And here is memory useage:

```
Node 1: Data usage is 0%(2487 32K pages of total 393216)
Node 1: Index usage is 0%(2205 8K pages of total 262272)
Node 2: Data usage is 0%(2487 32K pages of total 393216)
Node 2: Index usage is 0%(2205 8K pages of total 262272)
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have been resolve this problem:

1. Add parameter on JDBC URL **rewriteBatchedStatements=true** to make batch insert can submit at one SQL like (**but you should control the size**):

   insert into table_name(...) values(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

This can saving a lot of TCP communication times, if haven't add this parameter, MySQL connector will do below behavior as default (SQL commit one by one):

```
insert into table_name(...) values(1,2,3);
insert into table_name(...) values(4,5,6);
insert into table_name(...) values(7,8,9);
```

2. When export MySQL data using mysqldump, you can add parameter **net_buffer_length=8192** to control every SQL line size, without this parameter the insert statement will be like below:

   insert into table_name(...) values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)....

all table data will append at one SQL, it's hard to import back when the data is so BIG and UNDO log maybe full.

If you add **extended-insert=false** the SQL will be like:

```
insert into table_name(...) values(1,2,3);
insert into table_name(...) values(4,5,6);
insert into table_name(...) values(7,8,9);
```

It maybe spend a lot of time to import when data is too big.